# Live streaming from webcam to Android Device

Tags: android, webcam

Would it be possible to attain video from a webcam, and display it on﻿ an android device? Say, the webcam is displayed on a computer, and the android device streams the live video feed from the computer to the Android Device?

Can someone guide me on how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

You will have to code your own simple server which captures the raw bytes from the webcam and turns them into `Bitmap`.
The server will then listen for phones to connect on a specific port (greater than 1024) and then send the `Bitmap`s to them.

On the phone, you will have to make an app that connects to that port, gets the data, decodes it and then displays it on the screen.

Basically, you are sending a lot of `Bitmap` over the wire and at a very fast rate.

Or, you can look into [YAWCam](http://www.yawcam.com/), or [android-eye](https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye) for video streaming. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your advice so far. However, Im having some difficulty with the android eye app. right now it streams video of my phone to the pc. Is there a source code where I can reverse the stated process?

Comment: You can do like I said, code a very simple server of your own. I should not exceed a couple hundred lines of code. It is fairly simple, you know :)

Comment: Uhm.. look into `ServerSocket` to create a server, a `Socket` for normal clients, `Thread` that will be created for each user, learn to use `LTI-CIVIL` library if you are on Windows because Java does not allow you to access webcam directly.

Comment: It is not so hard. Do not get disheartened if you have to code a lot. Remember: Take some time to roll out a good software than do it quick and release a bad software

Answer (score 0):

I've done this couple years ago using motion software (on the linux computer) and tinyCam on the android smartphone.  Motion does require a few configurations, but it very simple and straightforward, although via text. You will also need to open and forward ports on your router.